# History token fires twice if the URLhas a special character in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt

I have a code that is working perfectly fine in firefox and chrome, but not very well in IE.

I am using GWT 2.5.1 .

The issue is that i am sending a string to query via the URL. If that string contains special character like **%** or **^** or **#**. the valueChangeHandler is called twice.

The first one has the URL as it was fired. with the special character not encoded, but then it catches another value change event with the character encoded. (ie '%' in the first event catch,then transformed to '%25' in the second event catch)

Comment: Is that when calling `History.newItem` or when the token/URL comes from elsewhere? Also, which version(s) of Internet Explorer?

Comment: yes, it  is from History.newItem. and it is happening in IE 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 11 isn't officially supported in GWT 2.5.1 (I couldn't even tell which permutation is selected in this case; and it depends on `X-UA-Compatible`).

Try updating to GWT 2.7.0, where IE11 has been tested, and should select the `gecko1_8` permutation.

Comment: I have tested it on 10 (Using IE 11 Emulation) and it worked fine, and only sent one onValueChange for the history URL change. I cannot use another version for the GWT. It is the version all the teams is using. and i we are setting X-UA-Compatible to "edge" so the application can work on all browsers

Comment: You're free to settle on years-old versions, but then it's hard to complain when things break in browsers that didn't even existed back then (IIRC). Or don't set `X-UA-Compatible`  to `edge`, but use `IE10` instead.

Comment: I used the X-UA-Compatible to be set to "10". that seemed to be the most suitable fix for me.